# Intellij - Gradle - Unable to build - Failed to apply plugin [id 'org.ajoberstar.grgit']

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, build, artifactory, grgit

I am working on Intellij 2019.2.4 with Java 11.0.13 JDK and gradle 7.3.3 in settings.
Gradle-wrapper.properties file has - distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.8.1-bin.zip

I have tried manual proxy configuration and auto detect proxy too.

I am unable to build the project and getting following error -

```
    A problem occurred evaluating root project 'bbi'.
    > Failed to apply plugin [id 'org.ajoberstar.grgit']
     > Could not create plugin of type 'GrgitPlugin'.
      > org/eclipse/jgit/errors/RepositoryNotFoundException
```

My build.gradle has following

```
    repositories {

    maven {
        url jcenter_url
    }

    maven {
        url maven_central_url
    }
}
dependencies {
    //Check for the latest version here: http://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/com.jfrog.artifactory
    classpath "org.jfrog.buildinfo:build-info-extractor-gradle:4.9.1"
    classpath "org.ajoberstar:gradle-git:1.7.1"
}
}
   apply plugin: 'eclipse'
   apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
   apply plugin: 'java'
   apply plugin: 'application'
   apply plugin: 'org.ajoberstar.grgit'
```

If I try to comment the plugin org.ajoberstar.grgit , it fails on the artifactory plugin which comes latter in the build.gradle file as below:

```
   allprojects {
apply plugin: "com.jfrog.artifactory"
artifactory {
    contextUrl = main_repo_url   //The base Artifactory URL if not overridden by the publisher/resolver
    publish {
        repository {
            repoKey = repo_key
            username = artifactory_user_name
            password = artifactory_password
            maven = true
            
        }
    }
```

Note: Also I am unable to re-import the gradle project. It does not list the gradle tasks or build folders in the tab.

Pls provide a solution to fix this gradle issue.

Thanks